# How to use display sum() in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Mysql Query :

```
SELECT SUM(`Item_qty`), `bill_id`,`Item_name`,`table_id`,`Item_price` 
FROM tbl_billmenu 
WHERE `table_id` = 30 
GROUP BY `Item_name`
```

How should I've to code/implement this above query in codeigniter module ? please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the result of SUM and group field from Active record in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219709/get-the-result-of-sum-and-group-field-from-active-record-in-codeigniter)

Comment: This query is invalid [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) .. I advice you to provide example data and expected results see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
 $this->db->select(bill_id,Item_name,table_id,Item_price,sum(Item_qty) as quantity);
    $this->db->where('table_id', 30);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_billmenu');
```

Comment: @Swap This query is invalid [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) you can't mix a non aggregate columns with a aggregate column.